# Stack - How do I (force?) install an old version of a package

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

So I'm trying to install `ghc-mod-5.4.0.0`, which crashes with a bunch of other installation:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for ghc-mod-5.4.0.0:
    async-2.1.1 must match <2.1 && >=2.0.2 (latest applicable is 2.0.2)
    cabal-helper-0.7.3.0 must match <0.7 && >=0.6.1.0 (latest applicable is 0.6.3.1)
    cereal-0.5.4.0 must match <0.5 && >=0.4 (latest applicable is 0.4.1.1)
    directory-1.3.0.0 must match <1.3 (latest applicable is 1.2.7.1)
    extra-1.5.1 must match ==1.4.* (latest applicable is 1.4.12)
    ghc-8.0.2 must match >=7.4 && <7.11
    haskell-src-exts-1.18.2 must match <1.18 && >=1.16.0.1 (latest applicable is 1.17.1)
    pipes-4.3.2 must match ==4.1.* (latest applicable is 4.1.9)
    process-1.4.3.0 must match <1.3 (latest applicable is 1.2.3.0)
    time-1.6.0.1 must match <1.6 (latest applicable is 1.5.0.1)
    transformers-0.5.2.0 must match <0.5 (latest applicable is 0.4.3.0)

Plan construction failed.
```

So how do I force it to install that version? Is there a simple way to purge the stack installation cache or something like that?

Comment: Btw. Purging a cache should never be necessary using stack as it is designed to work with lots of different versions, be it libraries or executables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like

```
stack --resolver lts-4.2 install ghc-mod
```

should do the trick, otherwise I would do something along the lines of `cabal get ghc-mod-5.4.0.0` and `stack init`, `stack install` there. You might need to install/switch to a different ghc-version or use the stack equivalent of `--allow-newer`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but in `stack --resolver lts-4.2 install ghc-mod`, where is the `5.4.0.0` hiding in?

Comment: Stack packages have a fixed version within a certain resolver, https://www.stackage.org/lts-4.2 shows that ghc-mod has the correct version there